# Setting Development Environment to Production locally in Angular project template with ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, development-environment

Using Angular project template with ASP.NET Core where
An angular version is 5,
Dotnet Core 2.1

here I tried to set my local Environment to "Production"
as this command

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Production"
```

and then start  `DOTNET WATCH RUN`

after this, I am still having my environment in **"Development Mode"**

So is there is any problem? 
I think I am doing right
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside of `./Properties/launchSettings.json`, you'll have something that looks like this:

```json
{
    ...
    "profiles": {
        ...
        "DatingAppDemo": {
            ...
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Notice here that the value for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `Development`, which *overrides* the value you've set using the `$env` command.

To resolve this, you have three options:

1. Simply change `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` from `Development` to `Production` in `launchSettings.json`.
2. Use `dotnet watch run --no-launch-profile`, which instructs the `dotnet` process to *not* load settings from `launchSettings.json`.
3. Add an additional profile to `launchSettings.json`. e.g.:

   ```json
   "DatingAppDemoProduction": {
       ...
       "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
       }
   }
   ```

   You can use this new profile with `dotnet watch run --launch-profile DatingAppDemoProduction`.

Unless you decide to use option 2, you'll no longer need to set `$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as this will be taken from `launchSettings.json` as described.