# How to determine which environment asp.net core app will run in?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, configuration, .net-core

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1) states that `If ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT isn't set, it defaults to Production`.

My machine doesn't seem to have `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable set at all, as evidenced by running:

```
c:\>set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT    
Environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT not defined
```

So theoretically, my project (brand new from Visual Studio template), should run in Production, but...

```
c:\dotnet run
Hosting environment: Development
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You will have a `launchSettings.json` file inside your project that is setting the environment variable for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Development Environment to Production locally in Angular project template with ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355990/setting-development-environment-to-production-locally-in-angular-project-templat)

Comment: @KirkLarkin I thought launchSettings.json only applied for running inside Visual Studio.  I suppose that's not the case?

Comment: It says that it will use that .json when you are working with a [Dev] env (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1#development)

Comment: The answer I've suggested as a duplicate explains it and how to force `dotnet run` to ignore `launchSettings.json`. The link provided by @abn also covers it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yep, that solved my issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the dotnet run command uses the the launchsetting.json file.

You can execute the command with `--no-launch-profile` option so that run command does not load the launch settings file and thereby the environment variables.

If you want to use launchsetting file and sepcific profile setting from that file, then create one and use switch `--launch-profile <NAME>`

Hope this helps.  [Refer documentation for command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21) switches usage.

Comment: One not clear case is which launch profile is default?