# What is "dotnet run" default profile setting from launchProfile.json?

Tags: c#, .net, development-environment

According to MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?source=docs

and this SO thread
[How to determine which environment asp.net core app will run in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069740/how-to-determine-which-environment-asp-net-core-app-will-run-in)

I am still unable to determine what is `dotnet run` default profile setting from launchProfile.json?

Thanks, Piotr

Comment: [msdn example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Here **EnvironmentsSample** is the profile picked when using dotnet run.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
dotnet run --launch-profile "SampleApp"
```

This approach only supports Kestrel profiles for now using .NET 6. For e.g. the `--launch-Profile` only supports `"SampleApp"` which `commandName` is defined as `"Project"` in `launchSettings.json` file.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59481",
      "sslPort": 44308
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "SampleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7152;http://localhost:5105",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me out.
In addition: I learned that Imay also use the --launch-profile key with the 
"dotnet watch" or "dotnet watch run" command:
dotnet watch --launch-profile <name>

Answer (score 9):

I think the default is simply the first profile in the list.

Answer (score 2):

The default launch profile is called the same as the project that you are running. So, if your project is called `WebApi`, the default will use the profile called `WebApi` from `Properties/launchSettings.json` *in the project directory*.
That last part is relevant if you launch with `dotnet run --project <Projectname>`.